# Socket programming.sending files

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm trying to send a file between server and client but when I'm trying to write into socket I'm getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error.

```
//server side
package tcp;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerSock {
        static ServerSocket Socket1;
    static int port=2500;
    public static void main(String[] args)  {   
        Socket server;
        File filename=new File("C:/Users/Sudhir/Desktop/mot.wmv");
        byte[] serverBuffer=new byte[(int)filename.length()];
        StringBuffer msgFromClient= new StringBuffer();
        String timeStamp;
        try {
            Socket1=new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Socket is initialised");
            int c;
            server=Socket1.accept();
            BufferedInputStream serverInputBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            InputStreamReader serverInputStream = new InputStreamReader(serverInputBuffer);
            while((c=serverInputStream.read())!=13) {
              msgFromClient.append((char)c);
            }
            System.out.println(msgFromClient);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            timeStamp=new Date().toString();
            //String filename = "test.pdf";

            //byte[] serverBuffer=new byte[1024*33];
            String respond = "Server responded at "+ timeStamp + (char) 13;
            //System.out.println(respond);
            //BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            //OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos);
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(filename);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            bis.read(serverBuffer,0,serverBuffer.length);
            OutputStream os=server.getOutputStream();
            try{
            os.write(serverBuffer,0,serverBuffer.length);
            }catch(IOException e2){
                System.out.println(e2);
            }
            //String serverMessage=new String(serverBuffer);
            //serverMessage+=(char)13;
            //osw.write(respond);
            os.flush();
            server.close();

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

//clientside
    package tcp;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ClientSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host="127.0.0.1";
        int port=2500;
        StringBuffer msgFromServer = new StringBuffer();
        String timeStamp;
        byte clientBuffer[]=new byte[732419705];
        System.out.println("Client Socket is initialised");
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddress=InetAddress.getByName(host);
            try {
                Socket clientSocket=new Socket(serverAddress,port);
                BufferedOutputStream clientOutputBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                OutputStreamWriter clientOutputStream = new OutputStreamWriter(clientOutputBuffer);
                timeStamp=new Date().toString();
                String clientMessage="Calling Server on "+host +" port" +port +" at" +timeStamp + (char)13;
                clientOutputStream.write(clientMessage);
                clientOutputStream.flush();
                //BufferedInputStream clientInputBuffer= new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                //InputStreamReader clientInputStream = new InputStreamReader(clientInputBuffer);
                int c;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            //  while((c=clientInputStream.read())!=13){
                //  msgFromServer.append((char)c);
                //}
                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Sudhir/Desktop/sud.wmv");
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                int readbytes=is.read(clientBuffer,0,clientBuffer.length);
                bos.write(clientBuffer,0,readbytes);
                //System.out.println(msgFromServer);
                //System.out.println("end");
                bos.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: Are you are trying to bind to sockets to the same local port?

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at tcp.ServerSock.main(ServerSock.java:46)

Comment: @AnubianNoob i couldn't understand what you mean.Can you please eloborate?

Comment: I had this error with sockets... When you bind one socket to the local port 2500, the second one cannot be bound to the same port. You need to bind the server and client to different ports on the same machine. However, if they are on different machines then it is ok.

Comment: If i do like that connection is not established between server and client